# Is there a way to get fonts that do not come from or exist on the google fonts website to work with Codepen?

Tags: fonts, codepen

I found fonts I like outside of the Google Fonts environment, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to add them to the Codepen environment.

They worked great for me locally, just saving the fonts from "Font 1001" to a fonts folder in my css folder and using the following code to make them execute:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Ostrich";
  src: url("fonts/Oslo_II.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Ostrich-Bold";
  src: url("fonts/Oslo_II_Bold.tff") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Adler";
  src: url("fonts/Adler.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

"Font 1001" provides a permalink to their fonts, but they don't use the url format the codepen seems to like and I can't find an alternative way to use non-Google Fonts.

Here is the format that codepen seems to only except:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);
```

Here is a permalink from "1001" Fonts:

```
http://www.1001fonts.com/oslo-ii-font.html
```

It has no `?family=fontname`

So I guess that's a day ruiner.

Does anyone no how to get codepen to except the fonts I desire?

Comment: You have to use a link that is a font file for `src` and css file for `@import`. The permalink is a html file. It won't work. Try finding a link with ttf extension.

Comment: As long as the URL is on the web, and it's CORS is set to allow use by other sites, the direct font link will work as a `src` url for an `@font-face` rule so: you tell us? Try it, see if the console warns about CORS or something. If it does: you'll have to host the fonts yourself. Also, don't use universal system opentype fonts (ttf/otf/ttc), use the WOFF/WOFF2 versions. It's 2017, no need to use what was a best practice in 2012 but has since become irrelevant =)

Comment: @PaulWilson Thanks for the advice. It doesn't appear that the 1001 Fonts site offers a link that accesses a tff extension.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the info about WOFF/WOFF2 versions